# MVC 5 Error page not showing

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am having a problem with errors.

When entering in some invalid `View` data, I am getting an error related to the error page being shown.

I am entering the following:

```
<html>test</html>
```

In my `Global.asax` file, I have the following:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This is the error in the `Application_Error` function:

```
Message = "The controller for path '/Error/' was not found or does not implement IController."
```

In my `Shared` views folder, I have an error page called `Error.cshtml`.

Here is the code for the `Error.cshtml`:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    if (TempData["UITitle"] != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = @TempData["UITitle"];
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Error";    
    }
}

<h2 class="text-danger">
    @if (TempData["UIHeading"] != null)
    {
        @TempData["UIHeading"];
    }
    else
    {
        <p>Error</p>
    }
</h2>

<p>
    @if (TempData["UIMessage"] != null)
    {
        @TempData["UIMessage"];
    }
    else
    {
        if (Model != null)
        {
            @Model.Exception.Message
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Error</p>
        }
    }
</p>
```

Why am I getting the error:

```
Message = "The controller for path '/Error/' was not found or does not implement IController."
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I have added the following `ActionResult` in a `controller`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestError()
{
    return View("Error");
}
```

The error page is shown correctly.

Also, I have `ELMAH` installed with email logging of exceptions.

**EDIT2**

I think the problem is in my web.config.

I have the following in the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/">
</customErrors>
```

Whenever an error occurs, I am wanting the `Error.cshtml` to be displayed that is in the `Shared` folder. I am guessing that the `Error.cshtml` cannot be found as it is in the `Shared` folder.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: create an action in the controller and call return this view from that action method. can you please post how did you call this error page ?

Comment: I have done as you have asked, and the error page is being shown.

Comment: so it worked right ?

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message suggests that you need an action method that corresponds to the URL => '/Error'.

This action should then return `View("Error.cshtml");` (with the correct path).

If your redirection is in web.config file then try the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: {"Path '/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml' was not found."}

Comment: @user3736648 is the Error.cshtml file in Views/Shared folder?

Comment: Yes it is, I am guessing it is protected when it is in the shared folder.

Comment: You could try to follow one of the error handling procedures in the provided link http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc

Even if your Error page loads, you won't have the model in it as the model is an MVC object and you are already out of MVC context. The article has a thorough explanation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `Global.asax`

> **P.S:** Change the name of the contr4oller and action as per your
>   declarations and other mods as per ur need

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim exception As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
        If exception Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim httpException As HttpException = TryCast(exception, HttpException)
        If httpException IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim routeData As New RouteData()
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error")
            Select Case httpException.GetHttpCode()
                Case 403, 404
                    ' page not found
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "errorpage404")
                Case Else
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", "errorpage40x)
            End Select
            If httpException.GetHttpCode() = 500 Then
                'TODO
                'Logging
            End If

            'routeData.Values.Add("error", exception)
            ' clear error on server
            Response.Clear()
            Server.ClearError()
            Dim errorController As IController = New ErrorController()
            errorController.Execute(New RequestContext(New HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData))
        End If
    End Sub
```